# How to add holidays in flutter table calendar

Tags: flutter, table-calendar

I am going to develop a holiday app in flutter using table calendar package.how can i add only special holidays in to calender.In my code every month 20 show as selected date.i want to select specific holiday in all the months.how can i do this.

develop holiday calender using flutter

my code is below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:table_calendar/table_calendar.dart';


class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: TableCalendar(
          firstDay: DateTime.utc(2010, 01, 01),
          lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 12, 31),
          focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
          holidayPredicate: (day) {
            // Every 20th day of the month will be treated as a holiday
            return day.day == 20;
          },
          selectedDayPredicate: (day) {
            return isSameDay(_selectedDay, day);
          },
          onDaySelected: (selectedDay, focusedDay) {
            setState(() {
              _selectedDay = selectedDay;
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a specific problem with the code showing your best effort.

Comment: Please avoid questions like this 'i need complete answer with flutter code'. Everyone is here to help each other. You have to first show your work and post your code so that others can reproduce the same problem you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set any function there:

```
holidayPredicate: (day) {
          // Weekends
          return day.weekday >= 6;
        },
```